# Automake and libraries

Tags: autoconf, automake

I am trying to generate shared and static library with autotools, so far I have

configure.ac:

```
  # Process this file with autoconf to produce a configure script.

  AC_PREREQ([2.68])
  AC_INIT([FULL-PACKAGE-NAME], [VERSION], [BUG-REPORT-ADDRESS])
  AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE(memory,1.0.0)
  #AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR([include/memory.h])
  #AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])

  # Checks for programs.
  AC_PROG_CC

  AM_PROG_CC_C_O
  AC_PROG_RANLIB
  AC_PROG_LIBTOOL


  # Checks for libraries.

  # Checks for header files.
  AC_CHECK_HEADERS([stdlib.h])

  # Checks for typedefs, structures, and compiler characteristics.

  # Checks for library functions.
  AC_FUNC_MALLOC

  AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile])
  AC_OUTPUT
```

makefile.am in my main dir:

```
lib_LTLIBRARIES = libmemory.la
libmemory_la_SOURCES = src/memory.c
libmemory_la_CFLAGS = -I./include
```

and I want him to just create two files, .a and .so in this dir, but instead he creates ./libs dir and there such files:

```
libmemory.a
libmemory.la -> ../libmemory.la
libmemory.lai
ibmemory_la-memory.o
libmemory.so -> libmemory.so.0.0.0
libmemory.so.0 -> libmemory.so.0.0.0
libmemory.so.0.0.0
```

so what should I do, to just create one simple library in static in dynamic version?

Answer (score 4):

`.libs` is a directory specific to the internal implementation of libtool, in other words, you are not to think too hard about it. You get a `libmemory.la`, which represents all variants (static, shared, ..) that you built. They all will be properly installed as expected when doing `make install`.

Libraries use various schemes for versioning, and libtool has to default to something, which is why you get a libmemory.so.0.0.0.

Comment: Fine, but I don't want him to put those libraries there, I don't want to have to install them also. I just want him to put .a and .so files in the same directory where autotools are invoked.

Comment: @Andna: You don't have the choice of where libtool hides its libraries.  Everything in libtool is made so that you don't have to care where the libraries actually are.  Just use the `.la` file anytime you want to refer to the library.  If you explain the reason why you want to have the `.so` and `.a` files visible, maybe we can show you how to organize your project in a way that is compatible with the GNU Build System (reminder: Autotools are here to help you create a GNU Build System, not any build system you may be used to).